# Apache http-vhosts not the same as httacces?

Tags: apache, wamp

I have a new project created in symfony and I configured httpd-vhosts to bypass all htaccess files that exist in the project's path.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@lab.localhost
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp64\www\lab.localhost"

<Directory "C:\wamp64\www\lab.localhost">
  AllowOverride None
  AllowOverrideList None
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow From All
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ /web [L]
  </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:\wamp64\www\lab.localhost\web">
  AllowOverride None
  AllowOverrideList None
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow From All
  DirectoryIndex app.php
  Options FollowSymlinks
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
  </IfModule>
</Directory>

ServerName lab.localhost
ServerAlias www.lab.localhost.com
ErrorLog "logs/lab.localhost-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/lab.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

With this config it gives me Internal Server Error. If I set the AllowOverride and AllowOverrideList to All, it works as expected. The rewrite directves listed here are the same in my htaccess file.

Is there any difference between htaccess and httpd-vhosts? 
And if not, why doesn't my config work?

Thank you

Comment: What did your lab.localhost-error.log say when you had it set to AllowOverride None? The htaccess is just an extension of the vhost file essentially. It allows the user's to customize the site a bit more if the service provider decided to lock down the vhost file from being edited.

Comment: @falconspy It says C:/wamp64/www/lab.localhost/web/.htaccess: <IfModule not allowed here. I tested it further and removed the .htaccess file and it works fine but I don't understand. If I set AllowOverride None , why does it care about htaccess?

Comment: Remove the <IfModule></IfModule> and just have your rewrite directives inside <Directory></Directory> - If you know you have mod_rewrite being loaded at all times then there's no point in doing the status check.

Comment: Well, it works after removing AllowOverrideList None. Apparently, AllowOverride None and AllowOverrideList None cannot work toghether.